# Review pending for all devices for Standalone Wear Os app

Tags: wear-os, google-play-console

I updloaded Wear Os standalone app to the Play Store and it became publicly available there, but when I tried to download it Google Play tells that this app is not compatible with any of your devices. When I open "Device catalog" in Developer Console I see this picture:[image]. For almost every device the review is pending. What is going on? Is Google manually checking the app on every model?

Comment: How long did this take for you eventually? My review is pending for about 3 months now... And after contacting them, they started "investigating" which is going on for about 2 months now... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not checking *every* model, but they do check common configurations before publishing. And I'm sure you've seen the notice at the top of the Play developer console:

```
**Due to adjusted work schedules at this time, we are currently experiencing longer than usual review times**
Please expect review times of 7 days or longer.
```